# How to pause until the event happened in activeMQ

Tags: java, events, listener, activemq-classic

I want the method to wait until the listener's event happened. How should I achieve this?
In my program, I want to loop until the result of the event meet some criteria, otherwise, I will endlessly sending request

```
public void run(double r, double sigma, double strike, double s0, String t, int d) throws JMSException, InterruptedException {
  double actureError = 0.0;
  double epsilon = 0.00001;

  // iterate until the relative error rate is less than requested (converged)
  while ((actureError < epsilon) || (actureError > ESTIMATION_ERROR)) {
    sendRequest(r, sigma, strike, s0, t, d);

    Topic topic = session.createTopic("topic");
    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(topic); 
    OptionMessageListener listener = new OptionMessageListener(task);
    consumer.setMessageListener(listener);

    double absoluteError = y * task.getSigma()
      / Math.sqrt(task.getCount());
    actureError = absoluteError / (task.getAvg() + epsilon);
  }

  return task.getAvg() * Math.exp(-r * 252);
}

public void sendRequest(double r, double sigma, double strike, double s0, String t, int d) throws JMSException {
  // send request to the client
  MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
  OptionRequest request = new OptionRequest(r, sigma, strike, s0, t, d, null);
  ObjectMessage requestMessage = session.createObjectMessage(request);
  producer.send(requestMessage);
}

public class OptionMessageListener implements MessageListener {
  private Task task;

  public OptionMessageListener(Task task) {
    this.task = task;
  }

  @Override
  public void onMessage(Message message) {
    if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
      ObjectMessage objectMessage = (ObjectMessage) message;
      try {
        Result result = (Result) objectMessage.getObject();      
        double payout = result.getPayout();
        task.addPayout(payout);
      } catch (JMSException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

I am new to activeMQ, Can anyone help me? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Create a CountDownLatch set to one and wait on it in the main app.  Then you can have the onMessage method count down the latch when your conditions are met.  This also allows you to set a timeout value on the wait call so that your app can wake up and check if its time to shutdown or do other work etc.